# Extracting JPG Image From MP4 Video

Tags: c#, asp.net, ffmpeg

I am using the below method to extract an image from a uploaded video and placing the image into a folder.

```
    private string GeneratePreviewImageMP4(string FileName, HttpPostedFile file, string ProperPath)
{
    string inputfile = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(ProperPath), file.FileName);
    string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileName);
    string thumbpath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Reports\\TrainingLibrary\\Videothumbnails\\";
    string thumbname = thumbpath + FileName.Replace(ext, "") + ".jpg";
    string thumbargs = "-i " + inputfile + " -ss 00:00:25.435 -qscale:v 2 -vframes 1 " + thumbname;
    Process thumbproc = new Process();
    thumbproc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\FFMPEG\\Bin\\ffmpeg.exe";
    thumbproc.StartInfo.Arguments = thumbargs;
    thumbproc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    thumbproc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    thumbproc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
    try
    {
        thumbproc.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
    thumbproc.WaitForExit();
    thumbproc.Close();

    return FileName.Replace(ext, ".jpg");

}
```

The issue, is that once the image is extracted, I get locked out of the folder. No body has admin rights to that folder. We have to restart the Server just to restore access to that folder.

This is only at certain times, most of the time it works great, but one out of ten times there will be an issue.

Anyone now why this is happening? Does it play the video to extract the image, but does not stop the video?

Comment: is this a folder on you Domain / Network..? if so do you have a network admin? could this be a Policy Issue,

Comment: This is on our own private Server. The same server our site is on. The ffmpeg is in the C folder. I do not believe so. We have all admin rights to the server.

Comment: who administers the server.. I am sure that there are some policy's setup on that server and perhaps there is a policy in regards to the number of files being uploaded / saved to a folder in regards to if that machine thinks it's being attacked.. permission in my opinion don't just change themselves.. could this be on a user by user basis meaning works for some but not others..? how do you have the permissions setup is it based on login in or a group..AD, IIS_USERS etc...

Comment: We use SessionID for identity. The server Is in our Server Room. I am only saving one video and saving one image. I will speak to the Network Admin to make sure he cant think of anything.

Comment: If you want to seek the file the `-ss` parameter needs to be entered before `-i`. Otherwise it will decode the file instead of seeking until the timestamp reaches your value. You're wasting resources.

Comment: how are you declaring your Session Variable I think that you should use `HttpContext.Current.Session` instead of Session they have way different expected results and you probably have that Session Variable losing it's value..

Comment: This site has been running for years, there is no issue with the Session. We use the session for lots of things.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try calling Dispose on thumbproc after you are done using it
2. Try using a lock:

   ```
   lock (_aStaticObject)    
   {    
     //All the code above    
   }
   ```

A word of warning, it can be bad for performance to use a lock inside of a http request (thou shall not mess with thy server's threads), which is why this type of thing belongs in a job.

Comment: Dispose did not work. I think I solved it. Its that dumb thumbproc.WaitForExit(); Basically WaitForExit tells windows that its ok to wait for as long as the program needs.

Comment: Glad you found a workaround, but I don't think that gets to the root cause of your problem. The real question is, why is wait for exit not returning?